# Prove that if $\mathcal{P}(A)\cup\mathcal{P}(B)$=$\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$ then $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Seems obvious but I doubt how to show it step by step... I could prove the reverse statement (if $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$ then $\mathcal{P}(A)\cup\mathcal{P}(B)=\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$), but it doesn't help.

 I saw a hint that it's easy to prove by negation, but I cant see how...
Thanks for help at advance!

Edit: $\mathcal{P}(X)$ notes the powerset of $X$

Comment: Plus, the "reverse" would be a completely different result, maybe you were thinking about the *contrapositive*.

Comment: @learning union of two power sets

Comment: @PeldePinda no, I wrote correct

Comment: For $\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$ to equal $\mathcal{P}(A)\cup\mathcal{P}(B)$ one must have $A\cup B\in \mathcal{P}(A)$ or $A\cup B\in \mathcal{P}(B)$.

Comment: @cronos2 I don't know what is contrapositive statement... I mean that I could prove statement if change "if" and "then" parts. Reverse is not a negation

Comment: As far as I can tell, the $\cap$'s in the title used to be $\cup$'s as in the question.

Comment: @AndreasBlass thanks, fixed

Comment: @MarinaRappoport contrapositive is showing $\neg b \implies \neg a$, which is equivalent to $a \implies b$. $b \implies a$ is **NOT** equivalent.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345978/prove-that-if-mathcal-pa-cup-mathcal-pb-mathcal-pa-cup-b-then-eithe contains enough, no?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

If $A \not\subset B$ nor $B \not\subset A$ then $\exists a \in A \setminus B, b \in B \setminus A$. Think about some element of $\mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$ that couldn't possibly belong to $\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)$.

Edit:

thinking about your comment it could actually constitute a proof (just for the finite case)

Clearly $|\mathcal{P}(A)| = 2^{|A|}, |\mathcal{P}(B)| = 2^{|B|}$.

$|\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)| = 2^{|A|} +  2^{|B|} - |\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)| = 2^{|A|} +  2^{|B|} - |\mathcal{P}(A \cap B)| = 2^{|A|} +  2^{|B|} - 2^{|A \cap B|}$
$|\mathcal{P}(A \cup B)| = 2^{|A| + |B| - |A \cap B|}$

Now if $A \not\subset B$ and $B \not\subset A$ then $|A \cap B| < \min \{|A|, |B|\}$. This way, $|\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)| = 2^{|A|} +  2^{|B|} - 2^{|A \cap B|}$ has, at least, three $1$s in its binary representation, while $|\mathcal{P}(A \cup B)| = 2^{|A| + |B| - |A \cap B|}$ has just one.

Comment: does it mean that I could prove it using size of P(A∪B) and P(A)∪P(B)?

Comment: or it's simply means that in ∃{a,b} ∈ P(A∪B) that not belongs to P(A)∪P(B)? could I state it without any additional steps?

Comment: The second comment is what I meant originally. See my edit for more about the first comment.